# The rebus means what?

Tags: rebus

Here is a rebus below. Find the meaning of this.

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please choose tags more carefully for your questions? You've posted three questions tagged [tag:riddle] so far, none of which have been riddles. On this site, `riddle` doesn't mean just any puzzle, but specifically a "what am I?" type puzzle, where an unidentified object is described through indirect clues.

Comment: I tried, but when I tried to write tag 'rebus' I writing came 'your tag needs at least 30 reputation.' So it isn't my fault.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo in the tag name? Creating *new* tags requires 300 reputation, but anyone should be able to use an existing tag like [tag:rebus].

Comment: I also can't type 'IQ' as tag.

Comment: Yep, we [abolished the `iq-test` tag](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5675/5373) because it doesn't really describe the *type* of puzzle. The tags shouldn't be about where you found it (e.g. on an IQ test) but what kind of puzzle it is (e.g. [tag:logical-deduction], [tag:pattern], [tag:lateral-thinking], [tag:rebus], ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be

> “red *command* o” → Red Commando.

Maybe it’s the name of a gaming clan or something like that

Comment: or could be same answer without the colour.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose it is

> Second in command